# Writing a string to a text file and then an array using numpy savetxt

Tags: arrays, string, python-3.x, numpy

I'm currently trying to make a program that makes a text file with the first line being 's16' after that it should fill the next lines with numbers.  My current code looks something like this:

```
import os
import numpy as np
file = open('workfile.txt','wb')
file.write('s16\n')
array=np.eye(4)
np.savetxt(file, array, fmt='%.3f', newline=os.linesep)
```

But this spits out an error at `file.write('s16\n')`, because I opened the file with 'wb' which means I'm trying to write bytes and 's16\n' is a string.  But if I change 'wb' to just 'w' then `np.savetxt(file, wut, fmt='%.3f', newline=os.linesep)` throws a similar error for not being in 'wb' mode.  Is there any way to reconcile these two?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
file.write(b's16\n')
```

In Python3, the default string type is unicode, so you have use the extra `b` to mark byte strings.

`savetxt` (and the `load` counterparts) works with byte strings.  So you are right to open the file with 'wb'.

Check the `savetxt` docs - I think you can give it header and trailer lines (the may still need the `b` - unless `savetxt` does the conversion).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!  The only problem is that file.write(b's16\n') seemingly doesn't create a newline and when np.savetxt(file, array, fmt='%.3f', newline=os.linesep) runs 's16' is in the same row as the first row or np.eye(4)

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer on your question but I hope it may still help.

I have stopped using numpy to write and load files and rather use  pickle.
This package deals with different data-types and list/arrays a lot better than numpy does.

An example code fragment:

```
import pickle
f = open("myfile.txt", 'w')
pickle.dump("My string", f)
```

One can also open a file to read only or read&write. I highly recommend this package.

Comment: `savetxt` writes text, in the common CSV format.  So its files can be read/written by other programs, including spread sheets.  `pickle` is Python specific.